# How connect codeigniter 2 to informix via DSN

Tags: codeigniter-2, informix

Hello i have a dsn via odbc connection in my machine. When connect with pure php it´s work.

```
 $_dsn= "informix:DSN=araucaria";
 $pdo = new PDO($this->_dsn);
 $pdo->setAttribute(3, 2);
```

How connect codeigniter 2 vía dsn ? My Database CI configuration like this

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'informix:DSN=araucaria';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci'; 
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Help me please!

Comment: Codeigniter **is** "pure PHP". What do you mean, what's the issue, what have you tried, what's the desired response, what are you actually receiving?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE=28000, SQLDriverConnect: -951 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Incorrect password or user comercio@172.20.12.128[tamarugo] is not known on the database

Comment: Try `$db['default']['dsn'] = "informix:DSN=araucaria"` (ref https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html)

Comment: Not work, same result

Comment: Al parecer ahora connecta, pero me tira el siguiente error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY010]: Function sequence error: -11067 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Function sequence error. (SQLFetchScroll[-11067] at ..\pecl\pdo_informix\informix_statement.c:859)' in C:\wamp\www\framework\CodeIgniter-2.2.6\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_result.php:48 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\framework\CodeIgniter-2.2.6\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_result.php(48):